Getting `Connector not connected` error with wagmi
I'm integrating Wagmi into my Next.js application to handle contract simulation in the backend with tRPC. However, I'm encountering an error message stating Connector not connected. I've attempted to follow the documentation diligently, yet the issue persists both on the backend and frontend. Despite ensuring that the wallet is connected, the error persists. I'm utilizing the Rainbow Kit, but I'm uncertain whether the problem lies with Wagmi or the Rainbow Kit.
Here is my Wagmi config.
import { http, createConfig } from "@wagmi/core";
import { mainnet } from "@wagmi/core/chains";
import { injected } from "wagmi/connectors";

export const config = createConfig({
  chains: [mainnet],
  connectors: [injected()],
  ssr: true,
  transports: {
    [mainnet.id]: http(),
  },
});


any solution, im stuck here?

@Buchi Unfortunately, there was nothing, so I switched to Viem.

import { http, createConfig } from "@wagmi/core";
import { mainnet } from "@wagmi/core/chains";
import { injected } from "wagmi/connectors";
export const config = createConfig({
chains: [mainnet],
connectors: [injected()],
ssr: true,
transports: {
[mainnet.id]: http(),
},
});
